# Objective C class method `(unsigned long long)`

Tags: ios, objective-c, reverse-engineering, arm64, frida

I am currently reverse engineering an app for pen-testing.

I ran over a method name called 'hash', but I am struggling understanding the type of this function is.

/* @class SearchRequest */

```
-(unsigned long long)hash {
    r0 = [self terms];
    r0 = [r0 retain];
    r20 = r0;
    r22 = [r0 hash];
    r0 = [self searchFilters];
    r0 = [r0 retain];
    r23 = r0;
    r22 = [r0 hash] ^ r22;
    r0 = [self categoryFilters];
    r0 = [r0 retain];
    r21 = r22 ^ [r0 hash];
    [r0 release];
    [r23 release];
    [r20 release];
    r0 = r21;
    return r0;
}
```

What I was able to disassemble.

It appears that it calls the method searchFilters, categoryFilters, terms.

I'm not sure what release, retain stands, for. And also I don't quite understand `-(unsigned long long)hash`, is unsgined long long the method type? It would be helpful to understand overall what this function is trying to achieve or what it outputs to. I have little no background working with Objective-C for context.

Using Frida, I've seen that the return value of this function usually is 0x0, which I assume means `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Retain/release are calls inserted by the compiler to add automatic reference counting of objects, to know when they should be `- [NSObject dealloc]`, originally retain/release/autorelease was done manually by the programmer, but I don't think very few people do it manually any more. `- [NSObject hash]` is a method all objects acquire from the base `NSObject` class they ultimately descend from, which by default I think just uses the objects address, you overwrite it and `- [NSObject isEqual:]` if you want to change what it means for two objects to be equal. Objects like `NSSet`, `NSDictionary`, use a `- [NSObject hash]` to speed up `- [NSObject isEqual:]` comparisons and insert them in a hash table, the value of `- [NSObject hash]` is used to find a place for the object and `- [NSObject isEqual:]` is used to further discern between two objects that have the same `- [NSObject hash]` value but may or may NOT still be equal, its possible for two objects to be NOT equal but still have the same hash value, but it's NOT possible for to objects to be equal but have different hash values, that would be a bug, all objects that are considered equal should have the same hash value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To further understand, hash is nothing but an int representation of key, value pair, right?  r0 = [self searchFilters];
    r0 = [r0 retain];
    r23 = r0;
    r22 = [r0 hash] ^ r22;
Does this piece of code, basically grabs searchFilters hash? Can you help me understand this piece and what SearchFilters is playing main role at?

Comment: Sort of except a single hash can map to multiple objects that have the same hash value but are not equal, so a hash maps to another set of objects, I don't know how Apple does this, it could be an array that is enumerated through to find the isEqual object, or it could be hash tables themselves that use a different sizes, but then they would still have to handle hash collisions still.